# Use external configuration for deployed war

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, configuration-files

For security reasons, I have to store the passwords in an external `application.yml` (outside the `war`), which should be loaded by the deployed `war` on runtime.

Do you know where do I have to place the external configuration file? Do I have to configure some properties?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have a war file which contains a spring-boot application, in general there are more options to manage your properties, check out the document here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

I will recommend you 2 different approaches:

1. Set your properties as environment variables, there is much easier way to manage properties if you have a separate container for your application.
2. Otherwise spring provides you the possibility to override properties using commandline argument, you can do something like:  `java -jar myproject.war --spring.config.location=file:/default.properties`

Comment: Should it be an application.properties file? Or can I also use application.yml? I tried overried the property but this is not working: -Dspring.config.location=file:D:\tomcat\..\webapps\application-develop.yml

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store confidential data in the server, then please add `<Environment>` to the 
 `context.xml` file of tomcat server. Example:  `<Environment name="user.password" value="XXXXXXXX" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>`. You can access them as properties in spring context.